# ASP.NET compare end time and start time with customvalidator

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have two text boxs for time input. I'm trying to compare two time with format : 10:14:23 AM. Then End-TIme must be greater or equal to Start-Time. The ASP.NET CompareValidator doesnt offer the time type, so I'm thinking of using the Customvalidator. I never use Customvalidator to compare the two text boxs for time input before. How to compare the two time? Thank you.

Comment: Haven't done your homework?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the MSDN entry for the CustomValidator? It specifies usage and gives an example of how to use it:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
                            <asp:CompareValidator 
                                ID="ClosedTime_CompareValidator" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToCompare="OpenedTimeTextBox" 
                                ControlToValidate="ClosedTimeTextBox" 
                                ValidationGroup="Submit" 
                                Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
                                Display="Dynamic">
                                <img 
                                    src="./FormImages/warning.gif" 
                                    alt="The entry is not recognizabledate."/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)